# How to compare two array in Jack (cours from Nand2Tetris)?

Tags: nand2tetris

I need to compare two array in the cours Nand2Tetris

```
let arrayIsOK = true;
let i = 0;
while(i<5){
    if (~(arrayLevel1[i]=arrayLevel2[i])){
        let arrayIsOK = false;
        //do Output.printInt(i);
        do Output.printString(arrayLevel1[i]);
        do Output.printString(" ");
        do Output.printString(arrayLevel2[i]);
        do Output.println();
    }
    let i = i + 1;
}
if (arrayIsOK){
    do Output.printString("GOOD!!!");
}
else{
    do Output.printString("NOT GOOD!!!");
}
```

But is return NOT GOOD!!!

Answer (score 0):

you dont put the result of the if in 
{}
you should write it like this

```
let arrayIsOK = true;
let i = 0;
while(i<5) 
{
    if (~(arrayLevel1[i]=arrayLevel2[i]))
      {
        let arrayIsOK = false;
       }
        //do Output.printInt(i);
        do Output.printString(arrayLevel1[i]);
        do Output.printString(" ");
        do Output.printString(arrayLevel2[i]);
        do Output.println();
    }
    let i = i + 1;
}
if (arrayIsOK){
    do Output.printString("GOOD!!!");
}
else{
    do Output.printString("NOT GOOD!!!");
}
```